# Cygwin - gcc-java installed but cannot call

Tags: cygwin, gcc

I'm running Cygwin on Windows 7, with environment variables set up correctly (as far as I can tell).

When I do this gcc-java shows up:

```
cygcheck-c
..
gcc-core             3.4.4-999            OK
gcc-g++              3.4.4-999            OK
gcc-java             3.4.4-999            OK <---
gcc-mingw-core       20050522-3           OK
..
```

When I call gcc-java, I get a command not found error. In `C:\cygwin\bin` the `gcc-java` binary is not there, yet it claims to be installed (tried reinstalling). I can call all other commands in `\bin\`

Answer (score 1):

The binary isn't called gcc-java, it's called gcj.

[This link](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=gcc-java/gcc-java-3.4.4-3&grep=gcc-java) shows you the contents of the gcc-java package, which reveals this,

```
Mon Dec 18 00:56:14 2006         100470 usr/bin/gcj.exe
```